# How to Optimize G1's Pause Time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

My JAVA_OPTS is

```
-server -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=384m -Xmn2g -Xloggc:/home/admin/logs/gc.log 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300
```

I'm satisfied with the frequency of Full GC,and the timespan between two GCs is 5 hours or longer.
One of Full GCs' log is:

```
2016-11-29T03:59:18.009+0800: 385603.123: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  4066M->1197M(4096M), 2.5124454 secs]
   [Eden: 0.0B(2048.0M)->0.0B(2048.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 4066.4M(4096.0M)->1197.1M(4096.0M)], [Metaspace: 168228K->167780K(1206272K)]
[Times: user=3.24 sys=0.00, real=2.52 secs]
```

Is the Full GC of G1 **Stop The World** ? If so,the pause time is longer than 1 second,which is unacceptable.How to optimize ?

Comment: Try setting -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70, it's default value is 45% of heap occupancy which maybe what is causing it to full GC too early.

Comment: @fn. PS:I'm satisfied with the frequency of Full GC,and the timespan between two GCs is 5 hours or longer. I concern the the length of  pause time.

Comment: Full GCs should not happen at all with G1, consider them a soft failure mode. Concurrent cycles / mixed collections should do the job all the time. Upload a complete GC log somewhere or anlyze it yourself with [gcviewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer)

Comment: @yichudu I agree with the8472, try running a tool to give you some insight, like gceasy.io (web-based)

Comment: I got the reason.There is a timer task who loads much data,1.8G about,into memory for updating some collections.So a time-consuming GC is unavoidable,unless I adjust the heap to bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Xmn2g` is conflict with `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300`.

`G1` will dynamically adjust new generation size.

You should just delete the `-Xmn2g`.